# Angular Material + RequireJS not working together

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Could someone help me on this. I am trying to use Angular Material with requirejs. But its not working. Here is the code I used:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body ng-app="StarterApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <md-select placeholder="Pick" ng-model="someVal">
            <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
            <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
        </md-select>        
    </body>
    <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
        'app': 'app',
        'angular': 'bower_components/angular/angular',
        'ngAnimate': 'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min',
        'ngAria': 'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min',
        'ngMaterial': 'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'ngAnimate': ['angular'],
        'ngAria': ['angular'],
        'ngMaterial': {
             deps: ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria']
         }
    },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

**app.js**

```
"use strict";

define(['angular', 'ngMaterial'], function () {
    var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }]);
});
```

A similar question was already [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567822/angular-material-with-requirejs), and I followed by using hammerjs proxy but I am still getting the same error. :(

[Click Here To See The Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Llki.png)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer at the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ngmaterial/requirejs/ngmaterial/5thy1kTf5EM/BgVQCqeizE0J).

**Changes in index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <md-select placeholder="Pick" ng-model="someVal">
        <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
        <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
    </md-select>        
</body>
<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Changes in app.js**

```
"use strict";

 define(['angular', 'ngMaterial'], function () {
    var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }]);

    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], ['StarterApp']);
    return app;
});
```